# Get the nth element from the inner list of a list of lists in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [First items in inner list efficiently as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084619/first-items-in-inner-list-efficiently-as-possible)

Lets say I have:

```
a = [ [1,2], [2,9], [3,7] ]
```

I want to retrieve the first element of each of the inner lists:

```
b = [1,2,3]
```

Without having to do this (my current hack):

```
for inner in a:
    b.append(inner[0])
```

I'm sure there's a one liner for it but I don't really know what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Simply change your list comp to be:

```
b = [el[0] for el in a]
```

Or:

```
from operator import itemgetter
b = map(itemgetter(0), a)
```

Or, if you're dealing with "proper arrays":

```
import numpy as np
a = [ [1,2], [2,9], [3,7] ]
na = np.array(a)
print na[:,0]
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

And `zip`:

```
print zip(*a)[0]
```

Comment: I guess there's no other alternative left to achieve this. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm struggling as to what else I can think of... gimme a bit ;) - do you reckon `map(next, map(iter, a))` is pushing it?

Comment: it's nice, but slow compared to the others.

Comment: I like that `zip(*a)[0]` suggestion!

Comment: In Python 3, zip() returns an iterator, not a list, so you need list(zip(*a))[0], which ironically returns a tuple, so you need another list() wrapped around it if you need a list returned.