# How to do 2D slicing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I'm trying to do what I think should be simple:

I make a 2D list:

```
a = [[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]]
```

and I want to slide out the first `column` and tried:

1)

```
a[:,0]
...
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

2)

```
a[:,0:1]
...
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

3)

```
a[:][0]
[1, 5]
```

4)

```
a[0][:]
[1, 5]
```

5) got it but is this the way to do it?

```
 aa[0] for aa in a
```

Using `numpy` it would be easy but what is the Python way?

Comment: `[ aa[0] for aa in a ]` looks fine to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the nth element from the inner list of a list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188476/get-the-nth-element-from-the-inner-list-of-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

2D slicing like `a[:, 0]` only works for NumPy arrays, not for lists.

However you can transpose (rows become columns and vice versa) nested lists using `zip(*a)`. After transposing, simply slice out the first row:

```
a = [[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]]
print zip(*a)           # [(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]
print list(zip(*a)[0])  #  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Wrapt it with `list` and it's the output OP wants: `list(zip(*a)[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[x[0] for x in a]` is the clear and proper way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in numerals 1 and 2 works in numpy arrays (or similarly with pandas dataframes), but not with basic python lists.  If you want to do it with basic python lists, see the answer from @cricket_007 in the comments to your question.

One of the reasons to use numpy is exactly this - it makes it much easier to slice  arrays with multiple dimensions