# How can I get the nth element of String for list of list in python?

Tags: python

I have my txt file something like this.

```
[0, "we break dance not hearts by Short Stack is my ringtone.... i LOVE that !!!.....\n"]
[1, "I want to write a . I think I will.\n"]
[2, "@va_stress broke my twitter..\n"]
[3, "\" &quot;Y must people insist on talking about stupid politics on the comments of a bubblegum pop . Sorry\n"]
[4, "aww great  &quot;Picture to burn&quot;\n"]
```

I have a some code which want to access the 2nd element of each array. When I use the code from [Get the nth element from the inner list of a list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188476/get-the-nth-element-from-the-inner-list-of-a-list-of-lists-in-python) It is giving each characters but not the entire string.

What could be the best way to make a loop for getting second element?

My code is something like this.

ALl the tweets are in the tweets[] list.

```
cluster = []
for idx, cls in enumerate(km.labels_):
    if cls == 1:
        # printing cluster 2 data.
        # print tweets from the tweets array. like the entire line. But I 
        # want to get the String here not the entire line.
        print tweets[idx]
        cluster.append(tweets[idx])
```

Here, idx element is used to get specific queries. so tweets[idx] will print specific queries from the text file but It is printing the entire line like [2, "@va_stress broke my twitter..\n"] and I want string element only.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far. I also suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some debugging tips.

Comment: The link you provided was for a list of lists. You just have a list. Getting the second element (index 1) is as simple as `l[1]`.

Comment: Unless all this is inside a list itself, you can access every 2nd element with `myarray[1]`. If these lists are inside a list, you can do `myarray[ : , 1]` in which you select every index, then only the 2nd index of each index.

Comment: Can you please check the edited comments and code?

Comment: `cluster.append(tweets[idx, 1])`

Comment: It gives me error like below :

Comment: print tweets[idx, 1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are wanting is the string from each list. I am assuming you already would have a list of list parameter with each list from your text file.
hence you can apply this to get the values.

```
list_of_strings = filter(lambda x:x[1], list_of_lists)
```

Comment: how does this go against `list_of_strings[:, 1]` ?

Comment: @Kenstars Can you please apply your suggestion to my code? Thank you

Comment: @Antry I've personally not checked the processing time, I guess your way of doing it might work out faster.

Comment: cluster = filter(lambda x:x[1], cluster)

Comment: @Antry , I think the form of slicing however is not available in python2.x , could you confirm

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these method :

```
data=[[0, "we break dance not hearts by Short Stack is my ringtone.... i LOVE that !!!.....\n"],
[1, "I want to write a . I think I will.\n"],
[2, "@va_stress broke my twitter..\n"],
[3, "\" &quot;Y must people insist on talking about stupid politics on the comments of a bubblegum pop . Sorry\n"],
[4, "aww great  &quot;Picture to burn&quot;\n"]]


print(list(map(lambda x:x[1].strip(),data)))
```

or

```
print([i[1].strip() for i in data])
```

output:

```
['we break dance not hearts by Short Stack is my ringtone.... i LOVE that !!!.....', 'I want to write a . I think I will.', '@va_stress broke my twitter..', '" &quot;Y must people insist on talking about stupid politics on the comments of a bubblegum pop . Sorry', 'aww great  &quot;Picture to burn&quot;']
```

Comment: I'm sorry but It prints 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 too many times. like

['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6'

Comment: Mean It is just getting the first character of each line so if It is a line number [21,'xxx'] it prints '2' ,if It is a line number [331,'xxx'] it prints '3'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data=eval('['+(open('file.txt').read().replace('\n', ', ')[:-2])+']')
result=[]
for i in data:
    data.append(i[1])
```

The last 3 lines are pretty obvious, but here's what the first one does:

1. `open('file.txt').read()` opens the file and gets the contents
2. `.replace('\n', ', ')[:-2]` replaces the newlines with `,`, except the last, so that it's formatted like a list. Skip `[:-2]`it if the last line doesn't end in a newline.
3. `'['+...+']'` adds `[` and `]` for more formatting as a list.
4. `data=eval(...)` makes creates the list and assigns it to `data`.

Just in case here is what the final lines do:

1. empty list created and assigned to `result`
2. `i` assigned to each value in `data` for the following line:
3. appends the second value of each list within `data` to `result`.