# How to get every n-th element from a multi-dimensional Python list?

Tags: python, list

From

```
lst = [ ['a', 1], ['b', 2] ]
```

How can I get a new list `[1, 2]` from it?

`lst[0:2][1]` works iteratively, so it doesn't work.

Is that possible without any loops?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the nth element from the inner list of a list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188476/get-the-nth-element-from-the-inner-list-of-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use list comprehension

```
lst = [ ['a', 1], ['b', 2] ]
n=1

result=[i[n] for i in lst ]

#=>[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter(1), lst))
[1, 2]
```